# How to restore apps with iPhone restore? (in year 2020)

Tags: iphone, restore

*All Apple questions are stale after one year. Why? Because iTunes is gone and other big changes this year. So I am re-asking.*

I have a new phone and backed up my old phone with Finder. Now when the new phone is restored, none of the apps are there. I know how to install the apps and set them up. But this would require considerable time for dozens of apps, so I am seeing other options.

Comment: This has been true for a couple of years or more, not just since Catalina [since iTunes 12.7 to be precise, Sept 2017 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#Version_history]. Apps come OTA, they're not backed up to the Mac any more.

Comment: Worse, some apps I *can't* reconfigure. For example Grab. To set that up I needed to buy a local SIM card in Philippines to register my account. Now I need to back to Philippines (or supported country) to set it up.

Comment: If you do a “restore,” you shouldn’t have to reinstall anything.  I recently replaced my iPhone, had everything backed up, did a restore to the new one and every app was replaced, as it should have been.  Are you, perhaps, referring to a *reset*?  Can you expand on how you did this backup then restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup with Finder is the same as with iTunes, same is for restore. When you restore an iTunes backup, app data is restored from the backup and apps are downloaded from the AppStore. If you don't see any apps, make sure that you are logged in to your Apple ID and that you are connected to a good Wi-Fi.